# Is "measure" a verb or a noun in this contect?

Tags: word-meaning

> More attention, however, was accorded to the abolition of serfdom in 1861 and the introduction of zemstvos, a form of communal self-government, which **measures**, despite their inherent faults, became a genuine focus for democratic expression
>
> A history of Finland by Henrik Meinander

What is the meaning of "which measures" in this sentence?

I can't even decide if the word "measures" is a verb or a noun.

According to Cambridge dictionary "measure" means:

1. (verb) to discover the exact size or amount of something
2. (verb) to be a particular size
3. (noun) a way of achieving something, or a method for dealing with a situation.

I can't attribute any of these meaning to the word itself in the sentence.

Comment: I would say "which measures" is a dated expression if not archaic. Did you try to search dictionaries this term "which measures"?

Comment: @banuyayi — the book was published in 2011.  It was just poorly edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an uncommon use of "which", but "measures" is a noun here. You'd probably think it's a verb initially because it follows "which", and that usually means "which" is a subject, and "measures" is its conjugated verb.

Let's simplify the sentence a bit without changing the grammar:

> More attention was accorded to serfdom and zemstvos, [which measures] became a genuine focus for democratic expression.

Normally, you'd just see "which" in the [bracketed] part, but it's also acceptable here to add a noun after "which" that labels the antecedent of "which". In this case, "measures" labels "the abolition of serfdom" and "the introduction of zemstvos". We can only do this in *non-defining relative clauses*, and only with "which", not with "who". In fact, to use this structure with human antecedents, we just use "which":

> I enjoyed my classes with Slantzky and Jones, **which professors** would eventually mentor me.
> <del>I enjoyed my classes with Slantzky and Jones, **who professors** would eventually co-author my book.</del>

It would be more common today to see them phrased this way:

> More attention was accorded to serfdom and zemstvos, **measures which** became a genuine focus for democratic expression.
> I enjoyed my classes with Slantzky and Jones, **professors who** would eventually mentor me.

The structure here is slightly different, because the antecedent of "which" is now "measures", and the entire part after the comma is an *appositive*, not a relative clause.

Comment: It can also be rephrased as "the measures of which"

Answer (score 4):

It's a noun. The abolition of serfdom and the introduction of *zemstvos* are the two 'measures' being referred to.

Merriam-Webster has:

a step planned or taken as a means to an end -
'took strong measures against the rebels-

specifically : a proposed legislative act -
'sponsored an anti-inflation measure in the senate'